# Boost::program_options - print usage if no inputs provided

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I am trying to use Boost program_options in order to parse my program inputs. In general the docs provide the necessary info for parsing. However, I would like to make my program print the usage instructions when no inputs are provided and I can't seem to figure it out. There does not seem to be a "default" options nor can I find how to count the number of inputs provided (to test).

This is my code at the moment:

```
boost::program_options::options_description help("Usage");
help.add_options()
    ("help", "print help info");

boost::program_options::options_description req("Required inputs");
req.add_options()
    ("root", boost::program_options::value<std::string>(&images_root), "Root directory")

boost::program_options::options_description opt("Option inputs");
opt.add_options()
    ("verbose", boost::program_options::value<bool>(&verbose)->implicit_value(1), "Verbose");

boost::program_options::variables_map vm;
boost::program_options::store(boost::program_options::parse_command_line(argc, argv, all), vm);
if (vm.count("help"))
{
    std::cout << help;
    return 1;
}

boost::program_options::notify(vm);
```

How can I produce the following (i.e. if no inputs do `std::cout << help`)?

```
./test-file
>> print help info
```

Comment: How about custom validator feature ?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with `argc`

for example:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if( argc <= 1 )
      std::cout << "Print Usage\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I agree with @Roby. In this case just change the line: `if (vm.count("help"))` to `if (vm.count("help") || (argc == 0))`

Comment: @kenba, you are wrong. The 0 Argument is the program name itself (ie. if no parameter parsed, argh is 1)

Comment: Sorry @Roby, so it becomes `if (vm.count("help") || (argc <= 1))` instead. BTW it's usually `int main(int argc, char** argv)` rather than two `argc`'s...